# Editing field twig template for taxonomy term

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I would like to edit `field.html.twig` for `taxonomy-term.html.twig`. I've tried `field--taxonomy-term.html.twig` and a bunch of other options, none of them seem to work. What is the correct naming convention?

Clarification: I mean the template for fields used on the taxonomy term page, not the fields used in content type to reference a taxonomy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field type for taxonomy terms is `entity-reference`. You can use the field type for the naming of the field twig:

```
field--entity-reference.html.twig
```

Because there may be more than one reference field, it is more specific to use the field name, for example a twig for the preinstalled tags field:

```
field--field-tags.html.twig
```

If you want to use the target entity of a reference field as theme suggestion you would have implement this in a hook.

**Edit acc. to the clarification:**

If the field is inside of a taxonomy term, you have to add one more detail, either the field name or the name of the vocabulary:

```
field--taxonomy-term--field-body.html.twig
field--taxonomy-term--tags.html.twig
```